# Why is "pip install -r requirements.txt" installing packages in the wrong location?

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-venv

With an active `venv`, `pip install -r requirements.txt` is installed to the global environment while `pip install pandas` installs to the install to active `venv`.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04.6
- Installed python 3.9

I created and activated a virtual environment using:

```
python3.9 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

I see the terminal line begin with `.venv` and `which pip` and `which python` both seem to point to what is in `.venv`.

### Main issue

When I run

```
python3.9 -m pip install pandas
pip list
```

I get the expected output with pandas listed as an installed package.

When I run

```
python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python3.9 -m pip list
```

I see none of the packages from my requirements.txt.

Finally, if I run

```
deactivate
python3.9 -m pip list
```

I see everything got installed to the global environment.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: After you activate your *venv* you need to call `python` instead of `python3.9`; you can check the binary paths using `which python3.9`. See [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

Comment: Is your requirements.txt in your venv folder? if not, this may be the issue. The -m argument tells python to be ran from the active interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially figured it out.

Looks like pip could not find one of the packages since I did pip freeze > requirements.txt on a windows machine and it will not do install anything if it fails to install everything from a requirements file.

I am not sure how I ended up with things installed to my global environment but everything worked as expected once I removed the windows specific package.

Answer (score -1):

Which python version do you have installed in your machine? Probably it's something about **pip** and **pip3**.

Try :

```
pip3 install pandas
```